# Cannot see files after ddrescue

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I am trying to recover data for a friend. I have cloned their drive and `ddrescue` reported no errors.

When I try to access the destination drive I can access it, it reports 200 GB free space of 2 TB so I know there is something on it but I can't see any of the files. I think that `ddrescue` got all the files but not the filesystem. I was using `ddrescue` in Linux Parted Magic.

The command I used was:

```
ddrescue /dev/sda /dev/sdc /media/sdh2/log/log.log
```

The log file also reported no errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: Could you tell, when you cloned original drive, how it was mounted? I mean - had that drive write permission?

Comment: I'm not actually sure I just ran the command and it worked.it failed the 1st couple of times till I got the correct path for the usbstick for the logfile .But then it just worked and it has definatly cloned stuff from damaged drive to new drive I can open the drive I just cant see the files but the drive is reporting 1.6tb used.

Comment: Any chance that it's a permissions issue?  Did you try accessing the files using the owner's userid?

Comment: The reason I asked you about mounting is what I learned hard way once. Read carefully [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Important-advice).

Comment: Ok I going to try a few things today if they don't work I will reclone the drive making sure its not mounted thanks for that tip. I will let you know results.

Comment: Good news I think I've got the whole drive back .I removed the clone from my parted magic linux system put it on a windows 10 system ran   `chkdsk driveletter: /f /x` which rebuilt the file system /f finds errors /x forces drive dismount . If I find and files that wont open I will run `chkdsk driveletter: /f /r /x`adding the /r which locates and recovers bad sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Good news I think I've got the whole drive back .I removed the clone from my parted magic linux system put it on a windows 10 system ran chkdsk driveletter: /f /x which rebuilt the file system /f finds errors /x forces drive dismount . If I find any  files that wont open I will run chkdsk driveletter: /f /r /x adding the /r which locates and recovers bad sectors.